# Registering app for API 2.0 key without Oauth domain

Tags: support, api-v2, api-key, registration

I'm trying to register an app, but it states that I need to add an `OAuth domain`. But I have `Enable Client Side OAuth Flow` disabled, because I don't need it right now.

I basically have two questions:

1. Can I change the `Enable Client Side OAuth Flow` after registering the app?
2. What should I put in the field `OAuth domain`?

Comment: I had a valid 1.1 key. After upgrading to the 2.0 API, I received the "bad_parameter ``key`` doesn't match a known application" error. So, I went to register a 2.0 key, to find out that an OAuth domain is required. I filled in bogus (`stackapps.com`), because otherwise it won't let me register a new key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can change very nearly everything (and actually everything that's user entered) about an application after it's been registered.

You should use the domain you intend to host the client-side app under as your OAuth Domain.  While not strictly necessary, it's the sanest option.

Comment: It's a Chrome plugin which is enabled in SO chat and SO main (so it runs on the users pc). So should I add stackoverflow.com domain?

Comment: For a chrome plugin, you should use your "extension id".  Like, if your extension id is abcd1234 you can go to `chrome://abcd1234/whatever` then you register `abcd1234q.  Working from memory a bit here, but I know some other chrome extensions are doing this.

Comment: As you told me I can change it either way so I'll just makeup something nice :) Might be an idea to add this information anywhere (docs or on the registration page). Thanks!

Comment: @KevinMontrose: That's probably not a good idea (using the extension ID for the app's domain). I did that originally with Stack Alert but later abandoned it because the extension ID changes based on the key used to sign the extension - and since the Chrome Web Store provides its own key (different from the one you used for testing the extension) it can be a nightmare. A better approach I've found is to simply use `stackexchange.com` for the domain (which is enabled by default anyway) and have the extension use a new window to complete the authentication procedure.

Comment: @George - fair enough, wasn't aware of the signing differences.

Comment: @KevinMontrose and if i want to write js applet for linux os family? what is oauth domain will be?