# What to do with "OAuth Domain" in the registration page for a browser user script?

Tags: support, api-key, oauth2, registration, scripts

I want to register my first project so I can make more API calls without hitting the limit now that it seems to be good enough for others to use.

My project is a browser userscript that works with Greasemonkey on Firefox and natively under Opera and Google Chrome.

But it seems I can't register without providing an "OAuth Domain".

I thought OAuth was something only needed for apps which need to "log in" to access per-user APIs. My app doesn't need those APIs.

There's a similar question I just found after typing half of this one, but [it's specifically about a Google Chrome plugin](https://stackapps.com/questions/3294/registering-app-for-api-2-0-key-without-oauth-domain?rq=1). Those have an "extension ID" as mentioned in the other question, but userscripts do not have such an ID. And even if Chrome creates one internally, the userscript will also work on other browsers.

Should I just go with `stackexchange.com` as also mentioned in the other question?

Also, shouldn't this topic be specifically covered in the docs somewhere - if it is I'll accept a link to it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this is not very well documented. OAuth Domain is the domain of the URL where users are redirected after authenticating themselves.

You specify this URL in `redirect_uri` parameter of your authentication query. The doc says:

> **redirect_uri** - must be under an apps registered domain

and also

> The user is redirected to **redirect_uri**, with these parameters in the hash
>
> - access_token
> - expires - optional, only if scope doesn't contain no_expiry

So again, it's just a domain of your **redirect_uri**.

For the full info refer to [Authentication Docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)